# Cannot paint image created using CGBitmapContextCreate

Tags: ios, core-graphics

Under IOS I am trying to create an image by drawing into a context created via CGBitmapContextCreate.  The following is the code that I am using (which is similar to some examples that I found), but when I call it, nothing is painted. Note that 'context' in this example is obtained via a call to UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext and I can successfully paint other things into this context. Is there something that I am missing?

Thanks

```
    CGContextRef bmContext;
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

    bmContext = CGBitmapContextCreate(nil, 200, 200, 8, 0, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);

    CGFloat Color[4] = {    
        (CGFloat) 1,
        (CGFloat) 0,
        (CGFloat) 0,
        (CGFloat) 1 };
    CGRect Rect = { { 0, 0 }, { 200, 200 } };

    CGContextSetFillColor(bmContext, Color);
    CGContextFillRect (bmContext, Rect);

    CGImageRef image = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(bmContext);  

    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(100, 100, 200, 200), image);

    CGImageRelease(image);
    CGContextRelease(bmContext);
    CFRelease(colorSpace);
```

Comment: Where does this code appear? In drawRect? Is there a setNeedsDisplay anywhere? Yeah, and where did "context" come from? Did you mean "bmContext"?

Comment: Yes this is called from a drawRect, and as I stated the 'context' comes from a call to UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext and can be used successfully to draw other things.

Answer (score 1):

After much experimentation I have found the problem. It appears that I need to call:

```
CGContextSetFillColorSpace(bmContext, colorSpace);
```

Otherwise it appears to be a grey scale context and is expecting only 2 values when I set the fill color, an intensity and an alpha. This means that in my example above, the alpha was always zero resulting in nothing being drawn. Setting the context to a RGB colorspace fixes the problem.

Thanks to all who took time to look at my problem.